# Available memory is lower than installed memory on Windows 11 Pro

Tags: windows-10, memory, windows-11

I have windows 11 Pro laptop with 32 GB memory installed.
But the available memory is only 20 GB as you see in the picture.

Why is it so low? and how can I increase it?

[image]

Comment: Right Click on My PC and select Properties. In the Summary screen that comes up, what memory does your computer have.  I think likely 32 GB

Comment: The difference likely is hardware reserved. Can you confirm. Edit your question instead of submitting a temporary comment

Comment: Your system has an onboard Intel UHD Graphics 630.  This chipset shares memory with everything else (and thus reserves it).  Not to sweat! .. First, this is common for laptops.  Second,, 20gb is NOT BAD! :)  You *might* be able to control the AMOUNT reserved in your UEFI firmware (aka bios) but I think you shouldn't mess with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Available Physical Memory is not the total amount available, it is the amount currently available after the OS, programs, etc. are loaded.

I am currently using 9.6 GB out of the 15.9 (16) GB I have installed. Therefore it is showing I have 6.4 GB available left.

[image: Memory used]